# Is it possible to invoke an Action based on the date and time?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm looking into making an Action for Google Home that says a phrase at a specific date and time, and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible.

I have read Google's Docs on [explicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit) and [implicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit) but it seems those invocations all involve the user asking for the Action to start. I have also watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvyrvowZ4wQ) by Google on how to make Actions.

Ideally, this is how I would like the Action to work:
First, the user talks to the Action to enable it (this is because I have read that Actions aren't really installed, so I want it to be explicitly turned on somehow).
Then, every day at 5:30 PM (I'm starting with a very specific use case), without provocation, the Google Home will say a hardcoded phrase.

Is this possible, or do Third-Party apps always need to be invoked by conversation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there are some limitations in how you use this currently. There are several varieties of how you can do this:

- [Daily Updates](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily) can be setup to send a notification every day at a time selected by the user.
- [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) are more ad-hoc, and meant to be sent when a condition changes.

Both of these send a notification to the user that, when chosen, re-starts the Action (sometimes with a specific Intent). However, there is a current limitation that both only work on mobile devices at the moment.

- [Routines](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/routines) work slightly differently. They are meant to be hooks into things that people routinely do at roughly the same time each day - such as when they wake up or come home from work. They are tied to daily events, rather than specific times.

Making your Action available to routines that they setup may also be a useful way to say the phrase the user wants when they want it, but the user will trigger it as part of their routine. It does not use notifications, and is available on all Assistant surfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my question!